# spark streaming + cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming

want to add cassandra to the spark streaming

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % sparkVersion,
  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.1.8",
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.5.0-M2")
```

prepare jar

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "google", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("io", "netty", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "codahale", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("io.netty", "netty-all", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("META-INF", "io.netty.versions.properties") => MergeStrategy.first

  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

code

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf(true)
      .setMaster("local[2]")
      .setAppName(getClass.getSimpleName)
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
      .set("spark.cores.max", "1")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

    /** Creates the keyspace and table in Cassandra. */
    CassandraConnector(sparkConf).withSessionDo { session =>
      session.execute(s"DROP KEYSPACE IF EXISTS kafka_streaming")
      session.execute(s"CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS kafka_streaming WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 }")
      session.execute(s"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kafka_streaming.wordcount (word TEXT PRIMARY KEY, count COUNTER)")
      session.execute(s"TRUNCATE kafka_streaming.wordcount")
    }
```

got exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.isPrimitive()Z
        at com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec.<init>(TypeCodec.java:142)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec.<init>(TypeCodec.java:136)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec$BlobCodec.<init>(TypeCodec.java:609)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec$BlobCodec.<clinit>(TypeCodec.java:606)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.<clinit>(CodecRegistry.java:147)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Configuration$Builder.build(Configuration.java:259)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.getConfiguration(Cluster.java:1135)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:111)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:178)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1152)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createCluster(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:85)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:155)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
        at com.lowcosttravelgroup.PostCostsStreamingApp$.cassandraTest(PostCostsStreamingApp.scala:71)
        at com.lowcosttravelgroup.PostCostsStreamingApp$.main(PostCostsStreamingApp.scala:46)
        at com.lowcosttravelgroup.PostCostsStreamingApp.main(PostCostsStreamingApp.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/api,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump/json,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/json,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment/json,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd/json,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/json,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool/json,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/json,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
15/11/06 17:56:31 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
```

if exclude operation with cassandra, spark starts without any exceptions

Any ideas ? Any works github examples spark streaming + cassandra ?

BR!

Comment: The scala version is 2.11

Comment: the problem is the version of google Guava being used. Try adding it explicitly to your sbt dependencies.

Comment: Tried , which version for spark 1.5.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchMethodError usually indicates scala version mismatch. For example if you Spark is built with scala 2.10, replace your connector dependency with

```
"com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10" % "1.5.0-M2"
```

You can find other versions [Here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspark-cassandra-connector).

Comment: The scala version is 2.11

Comment: The use the 2.11 version of connector

Comment: Do you mean spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11 ?

Comment: Yeah, try spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11 or spark-cassandra-connector_2.11. Both should work

Comment: I am facing the same issue ..And I have tried the steps here.. Any other directions ? I am still getting the NoSuchMethodError

Comment: Umm you shouldn't need to add _2.10 here. What you were doing was correct. from http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html `If you use groupID %% artifactID % revision rather than groupID % artifactID % revision (the difference is the double %% after the groupID), sbt will add your project’s Scala version to the artifact name. This is just a shortcut. You could write this without the %%:`

Answer (score 0):

you should pass your packages parameter with ur spark-submit or spark-shell for downloading spark cassandra connector

--packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.5.0-M2-s_2.10

please pass the correct connector version for your code to work 
and write provided after dependency in sbt file 
 "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.5.0-M2" % provided

hope this helps